# Is there a difference between these two queries? CASE THEN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm migrating a system and I found a store procedure that has the following structure:

```
SELECT @amount = ISNULL(SUM(amount/
    (CASE WHEN (Table_1.column1 > 0) THEN Table_1.column2 ELSE
     CASE WHEN (Table_2.column1 > 0) THEN Table_2.column2 ELSE
     CASE WHEN (Table_3.column1 > 0) THEN Table_3.column2 ELSE
     CASE WHEN (Table_4.column1 > 0) THEN Table_4.column2 ELSE 
     CASE WHEN (Table_5.column1 > 0) THEN Table_5.column2 ELSE @tc_amount                    
     END END END END END ) ), 0.00)
FROM Table_1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_2 ON ...
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
WHERE Many_conditions
```

I changed it to:

```
SELECT @amount = ISNULL(SUM(amount/
    (CASE 
        WHEN (Table_1.column1 > 0) THEN Table_1.column2
        WHEN (Table_2.column1 > 0) THEN Table_2.column2
        WHEN (Table_3.column1 > 0) THEN Table_3.column2
        WHEN (Table_4.column1 > 0) THEN Table_4.column2 
        WHEN (Table_5.column1 > 0) THEN Table_5.column2 ELSE @tc_amount                    
    END ) ), 0.00)
FROM Table_1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_2 ON ...
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
WHERE Many_conditions
```

I made some proofs and both queries throw the same results. I don't know if this change is ok, and why it made of that way.

I'd like to be sure before to change it.

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: the change is ok

Comment: Yours is the more efficient CASE statement.

Comment: Thanks, this code is too chaotic...I wonder why they made it of this way :)

Comment: @russ op's  `CASE` expression is shorter and easier to read, but not more efficient

Comment: @russ, why is it more efficient?

Comment: Well a few things, the CASE statement is designed to 'ELSE' once really. Also, as you might be aware, mainly (up to a point anyway) if the query is shorter and easier to read then it is more efficient according to the execution plan. Surely constantly repeating ELSE and then repeatedly ENDing would cost more.

Answer (score 0):

The queries are equivalent. Yours is better. The original was probably auto-generated.